# Fluent nHibernate dictionary customType

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have problem with CustomType in Fluent NHibernate.
I have to save as Json a dictionary to my database.
I created a customType for this that implements IUserType interface.
There is no problem to save dictionary to database for first time, but when i try to update collection, nHibernate dont set a property as dirty and dont update it.

My Equals and GetHashCode methods

```
    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        if (!(x is IDictionary<K, Z>) || !(y is IDictionary<K, Z>))
            return false;



        var dic1 = (x as IDictionary<K, Z>).OrderBy(z=> z.Key);
        var dic2 = (y as IDictionary<K, Z>).OrderBy(z => z.Key);

        return dic1.SequenceEqual(dic2);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        if (x == null)
            return 0;

        return x.GetHashCode();
    }
```

The objects passed to equals method are always the same (recently modified) two object.
Anyone have a idea what i'm doing wrong ?

Rest of IUserType implementation code:

```
    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        if (names.Length != 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only expecting one column...");

        var val = rs[names[0]] as string;

        if (val != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(val, JSonSerializableTypeSerializer.Settings);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        var parameter = (DbParameter)cmd.Parameters[index];

        if (value == null)
        {
            parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            parameter.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, JSonSerializableTypeSerializer.Settings);
        }
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return cached;
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new SqlType[] { new StringClobSqlType() };
        }
    }

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(T); }
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
```

Comment: You mean, your `IUserType.Equals` implementation always get the same object reference for `x` and `y`? And what are your returning for `IsMutable`?

Comment: Your `Replace` implementation would causes issues if you work with detached entities. It should copy `original` to `target` for supporting `Merge`. Your `Assemble` and `Disassemble` implementations will cause issues if you use second level cache. They should at least yield deep copies, but maybe would it be better to cache (disassemble) the JSon serialization instead and de-serialized it on assemble. See [`IUserType` comments](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/UserTypes/IUserType.cs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am wrong, but I guess you have returned `false` while implementing `IUserType.IsMutable`.

Since your user type returns a `Dictionary`, which is a mutable type, and which you do indeed mutate, your user type must return `true` for its `IsMutable` property.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I had IsMutable setted false, but changing it to true didn't resolve my problem.

In Equals method i getting two object, and for example i have dictionary in DB with 2 element, i removing it in C# code and do commit - Equals method fire and -> x obj is dictionary with 0 element and y object is the same.

Comment: Ok. I think my deepcopy metod is bad.

Comment: Problem was in isMutable and deep copy implementation.

Comment: Yes, as your type is mutable, it should not return the same reference as a deep copy. (If you check NHibernate sources, you may notice they do not flag collection types as mutable, but this a corner case. They are mutable, but they do manage their state themselves (within a separate table indeed): changes to them does not change their owner entity, so for the owner entity dirtiness, it is like they are immutable. This is commented in [Hibernate source](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/CollectionType.java) by the way.)